# Better way to GroupJoin and SelectMany 4 tables to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on Blazor Server inventory system, and using repository design pattern.
I have to translate Left-Join 4 tables SQL to EFCore 8.

```
SELECT * FROM `product_master` pm
LEFT JOIN `product_catalog` pc ON pc.product_code = pm.code
LEFT JOIN `catalog_master` cm ON cm.id = pc.catalog_id
LEFT JOIN `separate_qty` sq ON sq.input_sku = pm.code
```

After I change above to EF using GroupJoin() and SelectMany(), the code become complicate as below:

```
var productMaster = _productMasterRepository.FindAll().ToList(); //Product item
var productCatalog = _productCatalogRepository.FindAll().ToList(); //Product catalog (N:1)
var catalogMaster = _catalogMasterRepository.FindAll().ToList(); //Catalog information (1:1)
var separateQty = _separateQtyRepository.FindAll().ToList(); //Product Qty (1:1)
IEnumerable<ProductListViewModel> productList = null;

productList = productMaster.GroupJoin(
  productCatalog,
  pm => pm.Code,
  pc => pc.ProductCode,
  (pm, pc) => new { pm, pc }).SelectMany(x => x.pc.DefaultIfEmpty(), (pm, pc) => new { pm, pc })
 .GroupJoin(
      catalogMaster,
      pmpc => pmpc.pc?.CatalogId,
      cm => cm.Id,
      (pmpc, cm) => new { pmpc, cm }).SelectMany(x => x.cm.DefaultIfEmpty(), (pmpc, cm) => new { pmpc, cm })
        .GroupJoin(
            separateQty,
            pmpccm => pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Code,
            sq => sq.InputSku,
            (pmpccm, sq) => new { pmpccm, sq }).SelectMany(x => x.sq.DefaultIfEmpty(), (pmpccm, sq) => new ProductListViewModel
               {
                 Id = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Id,
                 Code = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Code,
                 ProductName = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Name,
                 CategoryId = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.CatalogId,
                 CategoryName = pmpccm.pmpccm.cm?.Name,
                 Brand = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.BelongTo,
                 OriginalPrice = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.OPrice,
                 SellPrice = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.SellPrice,
                 Unit = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Unit,
                 InputSku = sq?.InputSku,
                 SepQty = sq?.InvQty,
                 Status = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.Status,
                 ExpiredPeriod = pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.ExpiredPeriod
            }
       )
```

It seem the properties assignment by ***pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.XXX *** is weird,but it's dramatically works and expected result same as raw SQL.

However, I would to know is it correct way to use GroupJoin() and SelectMany() to Left-Join 4 tables on EFCore?

And is it possible flatten the ***pmpccm.pmpccm.pmpc.pmpc.pm.pm.XXX *** to readable natvigation and populate the ProductListViewModel?

Thanks you for help.

Comment: Use Query Syntax. It is designed to simplify such constructions.

Comment: And do use navigation properties instead of manually joining everything. The code you show looks has all kinds of issues. You pull data into memory and only then do you join the data. When using EF you should leverage LINQ capabilities by letting the database engine produce only the data you need and let EF produce the object graph you need. You not doing that seems to be a consequence of this redundant repository layer. Query the DbSets directly.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv
 Had rewrite by query syntax, it is much better. thanks

Comment: @Cheung, as mentioned above `.FndAll().ToList()` is bad approach, you have loaded whole tables into the memory.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv Yes, i removed ToList() and much better now. Why I add ToList() for each stuffs because Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql throws (this MySqlConection is already in use) error. Some articles said add ToList() for each FindAll() method to let them resolve the data query in advance to prevent MariaDB connection is inuse. Finally, I found solution is set the DbContext's ServiceLifetime from scoped to Transient.
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5647